# Generate blob sasurl using SAS

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to get a reference to the blob and generate a SAS URL for it.

**How?** Without exposing my storage account key?

**What all have I tried?** Getting the reference to blob by using SAS (of blob container or storage account).
My references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

The exception that I see: "**Can not create Shared Access Signature unless Account Key credentials are used**"

But I do not (obviously) want to expose my account key! Is this even possible? If not, is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: You could implement an API that runs in Azure and has one of your two account keys to generate a SAS token. This way it will stay insied Azure. Or store the key in [Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) and retrieve it from there as soon as you need to generate a token.

Comment: Are there any other ways of using SAS to generate blob SAS? @RickvandenBosch

Comment: A SAS doesn't expose your api key. You need your api key when *creating* a SAS. You'd never have to share your key publicly - you'd create a SAS within your app.

Comment: Hi, you can check this example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-storage-managed-identity/blob/main/src/Functions.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: no, there's no other way to do that besides using one of the keys. You need one of the Access Keys to be able to create a SAS token. Here's why you cannot do that with an existing SAS token:

> The signature is an HMAC computed over the string-to-sign and key using the SHA256 algorithm, and then encoded using Base64 encoding.

This means the signature that is part of your SAS token is a calculated value. Part of that calculation is based on (one of the) key(s), since that is used to calculate the *non-reversible* hash. The fact that this hash is non-reversible means you *cannot* retrieve the Access Key used to calculate the hash. And therefor, you cannot use a SAS token to create another SAS token: you don't have an Access Key available to calculate the signature.

> When you create a storage account, you get two storage access keys, which provide full control over the storage account contents. These keys are **admin** credentials.

More information: [Constructing a Service SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-a-service-sas)

Comment: Oh. That means that if you regenerate your account key, the SASs are useless.

Comment: I have a azure function to generate the sas token, but it still need the access key, and for that I need to add it to the environment, is there any way to do this by code?

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso taken from documentation: _Both a service SAS and an account SAS are signed with the storage account key. To create a SAS that is signed with the account key, an application must have access to the account key._ To secure your Access Key, have a look at [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault).

Answer (score 0):

This is an interpretation of this [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-storage-managed-identity/blob/main/src/Functions.cs)

First we have this to get the accountKey:

```
    public static async Task<StorageAccountKey> GetAccountKeys(string KeyName)
        {
            IAzure storageAccounts;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(@"AZURE_TENANT_ID"))
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(@"AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID")))
            {
                storageAccounts = GetStorageAccountWithTenantAndSubscription();
            }
            else
            {

                AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity(MSIResourceType.AppService, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
                storageAccounts = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                    .Authenticate(credentials)
                    .WithDefaultSubscription();

            }

            IStorageAccount storageAccount = await storageAccounts.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroupAsync(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_GROUP"),
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME")
            );
            IReadOnlyList<StorageAccountKey> accountKeys = storageAccount.GetKeys();

            return accountKeys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.KeyName == KeyName);
        }

        private static IAzure GetStorageAccountWithTenantAndSubscription()
        {
            DefaultAzureCredential tokenCred = new DefaultAzureCredential(includeInteractiveCredentials: true);
            string armToken = tokenCred.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }, parentRequestId: null), default).Token;
            TokenCredentials armCreds = new TokenCredentials(armToken);

            string graphToken = tokenCred.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new[] { "https://graph.windows.net/.default" }, parentRequestId: null), default).Token;
            TokenCredentials graphCreds = new TokenCredentials(graphToken);

            AzureCredentials credentials = new AzureCredentials(armCreds, graphCreds, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(@"AZURE_TENANT_ID"), AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            return Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithSubscription(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(@"AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"));
        }
```

Where you need to define the next environment variables:

```sh
AZURE_TENANT_ID
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_GROUP
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

All of them can be found on the https://portal.azure.com/ and if you run `az login`

then you can do this to generate the connection string:

```
        private static async Task<string> GetAccountSASToken()
        {
            StorageAccountKey accountKeyObj = await GetAccountKeys(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"));
            string accountKey = accountKeyObj.Value;
            string accountName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME");
            StorageSharedKeyCredential key = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
            AccountSasBuilder sasBuilder = new AccountSasBuilder()
            {
                Services = AccountSasServices.Blobs | AccountSasServices.Files,
                ResourceTypes = AccountSasResourceTypes.Container | AccountSasResourceTypes.Object,
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
            };

            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(AccountSasPermissions.List | AccountSasPermissions.Read);
            string sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(key).ToString();

            return sasToken;
        }
```

And that's all you need.